# PHP: htmlspecialchars() and non-English languages

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm new to PHP. When I try htmlspecialchars() with ENT_HTML5 flag it works, but all non-English words are removed. I tried:

```
<?php

$sometext = $_GET['query'];
$sometext = htmlspecialchars($sometext, ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
echo $sometext;

?>
```

For example, I tried with query "Hello world, Привет мир!" (English, Russian). But it returned me "Hello world, !". I don't have access to a php.ini. Maybe there is a problem? How can I solve this problem?

Thank you, @deceze, I found the solution:

```
<?php

$sometext = $_GET['query'];
$sometext = htmlspecialchars($sometext, ENT_HTML5, 'Windows-1251');
echo $sometext;

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're *telling* PHP that your string is UTF-8 encoded, when it apparently is not. So PHP cannot interpret it correctly and drops all letters which are not UTF-8 encoded.

Actually save your source code file in UTF-8 and/or change the encoding declaration of wherever that string comes from or change the 3rd parameter to the encoding the string is actually saved in.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) if you need more information.